# from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, http, response

I am running a project in python 3.7 to obtain data from a server through a GET, for this I import the following:

`django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse`

When executing the project I get the following error as output:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse ModuleNotFoundError: 
No module named 'django'
```

Comment: Django module isn't installed in your environment. Run `pip install django` in your cmd

Comment: yes, I did it running a virtual python environment and still I get the error.

Comment: Your project interpreter is probably pointing to the wrong place then.

Comment: `pip freeze` Run this command and check `django` is installed or not in your virtual environment.